# Writing/Reading special characters from CSV (Python 3.6)

Tags: python, csv, unicode, utf-8, decode

Let's assume that I need to write and then read a list of strings with polish words in a .csv in Python 3.6:

```
lista=['szczęśliwy','jabłko','słoń','kot']
```

Since it's not possible to write *Unicode* characters in the .csv, I encode the strings to *utf-8*, so data is saved like this in the file (all inside the first .csv cell):

```
b'szcz\xc4\x99\xc5\x9bliwy',b'jab\xc5\x82ko',b's\xc5\x82o\xc5\x84',b'kot'
```

But I am not able to decode the data from the *output.csv* file using this code:

```
with open('output.csv') as csvarchive:
    entrada = csv.reader(csvarchive)
    for reg in entrada:
        lista2=reg

print(lista2)
["b'szcz\\xc4\\x99\\xc5\\x9bliwy'", "b'jab\\xc5\\x82ko'", "b's\\xc5\\x82o\\xc5\\x84'", "b'kot'"]
```

`lista2` is still a list of strings but with the utf-8 codification and I am not able to recover the special characters.

I tried several things like reading the file in `'rb'` mode, encoding and decoding again... But since I am new in these matters I didn't make it. It must have very easy solution.

Comment: Does it make a difference if you explicitly specify the encoding in the `open` call? Eg, `open('output.csv', encoding='utf8')` ?

Comment: *"Since it's not possible to write Unicode characters in the .csv"* That's bullshit. Who told you that?

Comment: @Tomalak How do you save Unicode objects to a file without encoding them in some fashion?

Comment: @PM You write them to a file that opened with the respective encoding parameter?

Comment: @Tomalak Indeed. I agree that (in Python 3) there's (almost) never a good reason to do the encoding / decoding manually.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1. Never open text files without specifying an encoding (this is generally true).
2. Always open CSV files with `newline=''` (this applies to the Python `csv` module)

So, assuming your CSV file is UTF-8-encoded, use:

```
with open('output.csv', 'r', encoding='UTF-8', newline='') as csvarchive:
    entrada = csv.reader(csvarchive)
    for reg in entrada:
        # do something with the data row, it's already decoded
```

The same applies to writing the file:

```
with open('output.csv', 'w', encoding='UTF-8', newline='') as csvarchive:
    writer = csv.writer(csvarchive)
    # write data to the writer, it will be encoded automatically
```

There is no need to do any manual string encoding. Write string values to the `csv` writer, file encoding will happen transparently.

Comment: This right here is the beauty of Python 3's treatment of Unicode. Specify the encoding once, then forget about it.

Comment: Lesson learned. I guess I have to get more familiar with all these matters. Thanks a lot Tomalak.